# iOS 7 Product Request not returning anything (iAp Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, in-app-purchase

I'm requesting for products and this is my class

```
class InAppC: UITableViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver  {
```

and product requst in viewdid load

```
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            var productIDs:NSSet = NSSet(objects: productOne, productTwo, productThree, productFour, productFive)
            var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
            productsRequest.delegate = self
            productsRequest.start()
        }else{
            println("can't make purchases")
        }
```

and this is the delegate function

```
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product found")
}
```

It prints **product found** in iOS 8 but I'm not sure why its not printing on iOS 7 device?
Delegate error says **Cannot connect to itunes Store**

Comment: @Tim what two thing?

Comment: Lol I accidentally posted mid message. 1. Implement the error handler and see if the request is failing for some reason. 2. If not, try defining the product request outside the method. ARC may be cleaning it up when it shouldn't. I have seen it happen before.

Comment: Confusingly enough it's under skrequestdelegate not under the product.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKRequestDelegate/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKRequestDelegate/request:didFailWithError:

Comment: @Tim it says "Cannot connect to itunes store"

Comment: Huh. This on a real device or the simulator? Does the actual store work on the device?

Comment: it works on ios 8 simulator, ios 7 simulator doesn't work?

Comment: It seems that the products request service in sandbox is down, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMurillo i think so because its not even working on device and iOS 8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296663/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-ios-8?noredirect=1#comment46791240_29296663