# "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, in-app-purchase, app-store

Last night In-App Purchases were not showing on iOS7 simulator devices but today I didn't even change the code and I started getting the same error on iOS 8 devices as well. this is my class

```
class InAppC: UITableViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver  {
```

and product requst in viewdid load

```
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        var productIDs:NSSet = NSSet(objects: productOne, productTwo, productThree, productFour, productFive)
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }else{
        println("can't make purchases")
    }
```

and this is the delegate function

```
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product found")
}
    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because it was listing all the products last night.

Edit- I just tested on my device running iOS 7 but I'm getting same error on device as well.

Comment: Maybe apple changed s.th... We experience this error today in our app for any development signed build (was working about 2 days ago), but distribution signed builds (from the App Store) just work. I also checked old builds from about 2 months ago, which were definitely working (even though development signed).

Comment: this is weird, it was all working yesterday

Comment: I'll do some further investigation and come back here, if I get it solved.. really strange..

Comment: @d4Rk sure I'm trying to figure out too from a day

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with apple servers, it is not working for us as well on any device. I will suggest not to change your code and just wait till things are back to normal.

Comment: hmm sure, will try again later after few hours

Comment: Yes I'm having the same problem with working code, try again later.

Answer (score 0):

This does not provide a solution for the problem, but I'm going to share my investigation here, for other people that experience these issues, too.

#### About the issue

Starting around March, 26th / 27th, it seems that all requests sent to the `App Store` using `Store Kit` will return one of the following errors:

- `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x18433a50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}`
- `Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x170272100 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}`

#### Affected builds

- **affected:** builds signed with a `Development-`, `Enterprise-` or `Ad Hoc-Profile`
- **not affected:** live builds in the `App Store` signed with a `Distribution-Profile`

Just filed in a bug report to Apple. I will keep you updated.

### Update

Looks like Apple got the issue solved, and IAPs are working again.